# How Do I get the username from Login Page and use it dynamically on all pages (Components) in React Native

Tags: react-native, session, components

I have this challenge. I want to make use of the username gotten from the login component, once the user Logs in and authenticates successfully, it should inturn save the username so it can used on all pages in the application. I am kind of new to React Native development,  so to use sessions i am not really conversant with it.

I would like to know How do I save the username from the Login form, so I can use it in all pages in the application. I tried doing something like

```
  switch(key)
  {
      case "BVN":
         this.props.navigation.navigate('bvn',{user: this.state.user});
          break;
      case "Transfers":
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Transfers',{user: this.state.user});
            break;
      case "Bill Payments":
        this.props.navigation.navigate('BillPayments');
            break;
      case "Checkbook Requests":
            this.props.navigation.navigate('CheckBookRequest');
            break;
      case "Airtime Purchase":
            this.props.navigation.navigate('AirtimePurchase');
            break;
      case "Contact Us":
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Contact');
            break;
  }
```

So that It can use the state on the other page, however , when i use getParam to get the user, it does not show anything. Why is this so?

Please I would be needing help in this case.

**Edit**

Here is what i am trying to Acheieve

```
//Login

Login = async() =>
{
    if(username =='james_hall' && password=='qasim1234'){
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(this.state.username,'1');
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
    }else
    {
        alert('Username or Password is invalid');
    }
}
```

//On Transfers page to get the account so i can use in Picker

```
 LoadAccountNumber = async() =>
    {
        const AccountNum = await AsyncStorage.getItem(this.state.username); //gotten from saved state
        //make GET request to fetch Details
        
           var searchAPIURL = 'https://uncoiled-crust.000webhostapp.com/api/searchData.php?AccountNum='+AccountNum;
         var header = {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         };
    
         fetch(
             searchAPIURL,
             {
                 method : 'GET',
                 headers : header
             }
         ).then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson)=> {
              this.setState({Fullname:responseJson[0].Fullname});
              this.setState({balance:responseJson[0].balance});
              this.setState({AccountNum:responseJson[0].AccountNum});
          })
    
    }
```

After declaring the state and all. It still returns Null. I would share my source code upon request. If need be

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you want the username even after the user kills your app from memory , you need to use the ``ÀsyncStorage``` as our friend mentioned above. That is a disadvantage, your app will spend some memory of the cellphone.

If you want the username just for sessions, that is, your username will be available for everywhere in the app after login, but when he kills th app from memory the username will not be there anymore. For this, you can use [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started). It's a big subject to talk about, so take a look at the link and you can ask me anything.

Depends of your context to discover which lib you must use :).

Waiting for your feedback. Thx :).

Comment: Please See Edits

Comment: ``ÀsyncStorage.setItem(key,value)``` works like a dictionary (key and value), so you have to write in the ```Login``` method  ```await AsyncStorage.setItem('username',username);``` After that, in any place in your app you can do  ```const username =  await AsyncStorage.setItem('username');``` to get the username of the user. You got it now? Waiting for your feedback Thx :).

Comment: i managed to get it to work and it works all good on ma app now. Now i have learnt how to create sessions in react native. Many thanks

Comment: That's nice! You're welcome. I'm happy your problem is solved. If you wish please thumbs up my answer :).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) to store and access the user info when your app restarts and decide whether to navigate to the home or login screen

```
const setItem = async (user) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
            console.log('data stored');
        } catch (error) {
            // Error saving data
            console.log('AsyncStorage save error: ' + error.message);
        }
};
```

Comment: AsyncStorage saves the username on the app, so that all other pages can use the same username and make REST api calls?

Comment: @Evans Yes, It can save the username and also can be the object of a user in the string and can use any screen of the app